# Change the image when clicked on it in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I a new to ember and trying to figure out a solution.
I have a template which contains images.
When I click on the images it should change the image.

```
applicaton.hbs

      {{#if feed.is_following}}
      <a href {{action "unfollow" feed}}>
      <img src = "unfollow.png" /></a>
      {{else}}
      <a href {{action "follow" feed}}>
      <img src = "follow.png" /></a>
      {{/if}}

Controller.js

actions:{
    change() {
    src:"unfollow.png"
    },
```

How do I change the img tag source from `follow.png` to `unfollow` and vice-versa when I click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/). Computed properties get evaluated whenever the provided property changes.

applicaton.hbs

```
  <a href {{action "change"}}><img src="{{source}}" /></a>
```

Controller.js

```
follow: true,
source: Ember.computed('follow', function() {
   return (this.get('follow') ? 'follow' : 'unfollow') + '.png';
}),
actions: {
    change: function() {
       this.toggleProperty('follow');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moogs.Thanks for your help.Its working.But there is slight problem with case.My image display in template is conditionally.I can changes the images with the simple feed.set('is_following',false),or feed.set('is_following',true), depending on the action.But for some reason I can't  do that.In your solution the follow.png get display at the first time and not the conditionally images.Please suggest something to fit my scenario

Comment: @MarutiNandan I think you need to update the first argument in Ember.computed to match the property you're changing

Comment: I am not able to do it.Can you please edit your answer and tell me what actually are you implying